Is there a way to connect to an oracle database with ldap using python-oracledb in thin mode?
I am trying to connect to an oracle database using the python oracledb library.
On looking at the docs it seems like python-oracledb doesn't have ldap support for thin mode. Is there a workaround for this. If not then, how do I use the thick mode and then later deploy the application with docker, as it requires using oracle instant client?
I tried using the below syntax to connect to db:
oracledb.connect(user=<username>,password=<password>,dsn='ldap://servername:port/cn=OracleContext,dc=domain,dc=com/servicename')
In doing so I get an error that:
DPY-4021: invalid protocol "ldap"
I also found a workaround which got a tns descriptor from using the ldap string. but on using that, I got another error:
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

The current Thin mode solution is the code snippet in the python-oracledb issue https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/discussions/71#discussioncomment-3918181.  If you need help with Instant Client in Docker, see Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python.

I was finally able to get this to work. The issue actually seemed to be with some credentials I didn't know I had to add.
